# What is the session about simplicity that Martin Odersky suggested during the "Scala with style" talk?

Tags: scala

The video of Scala with style is here: http://parleys.com/play/51c1994ae4b0d38b54f4621b/chapter21/about

It's around 41:10 that he suggested another talk.

I can not hear the name of speaker or the name of the session very clearly.

Could someone help me to figure that out?

Comment: The name of the person he is citing is Rich Hickey.  He is the creator of Clojure, a functional programming language similar to Lisp written on the JVM.  The talk he is referring to is apparently a "strange loop" talk, whatever that is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Strange Loop is a conference.

Comment: How does this match that definition of 'off-topic'? It doesn't ask for opinions or recommendations, it's a well-formed, specific question which has a clear answer. If you really have to close it, at least make it "too localized", for crying out loud...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The talk he's referring is "Simple Made Easy", here's an [InfoQ link](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy) for you.

A great talk by the way. For the most part it's language agnostic, so it's a worthwhile watch even if you're not interested in Clojure itself. I highly recommend it.

Quoting the InfoQ summary:

> Rich Hickey emphasizes simplicity’s virtues over easiness’, showing that while many choose easiness they may end up with complexity, and the better way is to choose easiness along the simplicity path.